# Solr data migration between AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, solr, amazon-ec2, web-traffic

I am planning to set up a Solr server on a EC2 instance. As traffic grows I might have move the solr server from a smaller instance to a bigger one. But this change will need to happen in realtime when the old solr instance serves traffic. So I am concerned that while doing this switch, some valuable data that might been indexed could get lost. Also the data from old server will need to be moved to the new server. There would be a significant time required to do this.

Also when the traffic cannot be handled by the largest server, SolrCloud will need to be deployed on multiple servers and the same data migration issue could occur.

Is there an efficient and a more robust way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you could probably:

1. DO start using SolrCloud from the get go, but just with a single node/one shard. At this point there is nothing 'Cloud-dy' here but not harm done either.
2. When traffic grows, you can create the new bigger EC2 instance, and add it to cluster. Now you have a 'working' SolrCloud cluster with a replica.
3. As needed, keep adding nodes, and creating more shards/replicas.